# Can you manually sort a list in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

If I had a list of words, e.g.

```
words = ['apple', 'boat', 'cat']
```

And I also had a list of numbers, e.g.

```
num = [1, 2, 0]
```

Is there a way to then sort the first list according to the numbers in the second list? I.e. The index of `'apple'` is `0`, so it should be last in the list, the index of `'boat'` is `1`, so it should be first, etc.

Comment: third answer is really very interesting using `itemgetter()`

Comment: why is 0 the last? it's very non-programmatic =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know indexes won't be repeated in the second list, and you know they'll be the same length in  you can create a for loop:

```
words_b = []
for n in num:
    words_b.append(words[n])
words = words_b
```

But thefourtheye already did this in a more compact way. This one's just a little more readable if you are not well-versed in Python.

Comment: Whoops, little mistake there -- fixed.

Answer (score 9):

```
words = ['apple','boat','cat']
num = [1,2,0]
print([words[current_index] for current_index in num])
```

**Output**

```
['boat', 'cat', 'apple']
```

The list comprehension method will work both on Python 2.x and 3.x.

Though I would **NOT** recommend this, you can write this more succinctly like this

```
print(map(words.__getitem__, num))
```

The same thing can be written in Python 3.x, like this

```
print(list(map(words.__getitem__, num)))
```

Comment: Ah! Simple list comprehension :)

Comment: Wow, that's even faster than NumPy arg indexing

Answer (score 2):

Using [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> words = ['apple','boat','cat']
>>> num = [1,2,0]
>>> import operator
>>> operator.itemgetter(*num)(words)
('boat', 'cat', 'apple')
```